# Webmethod authentication not passed

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, webmethod

I'm new to this AJAX approach when you're not supposed to use `UpdatePanel` but rather go with `WebMethod`s and `WebService`s. My main problem is authentication.

When page is entered or postback request is created, everything works fine. Authentication is passed correctly and I can access `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` and get my user identity object from there.

However this changes when I try to call `WebMethod` on my page. Call is passed correctly to server and everything seems to work just fine until i try to get user identity from thread. Then I get just `Anonymous` user instead of real one. Enabling session on webmethod didn't seem to help much.

Any ideas what might cause this problem and how to solve it? Someone mentioned that authentication cookie needs to be passed along with the request, but how am I supposed to do it?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:

Some clarification and code:

My application is written in standard `asp.net`. After some deeper research in legacy code I've found out, that all authentications are done in some base class from wchich all other pages inherit. Each time page is loaded, user principal are obtained from `HttpContext.Current.Session("...")`. I think this is far from good solution, but I'll need to stick with it right now. Problem was, `WebMethod` is not firing whole page lifecycle since it's `static`. I've fixed it right now by calling method that obtains user data from session.

I would like to get some ideas how this could be created correctly and what problems might be result of session based authentication.

```
PageMethods.SomeMethod(parameter, SuccessDelegate, FailureDelegate);
```

This is how I'm calling `WebMethods` right now. I assume it's passing all required cookies, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in comment above, the issue lies in legacy code that handles users. It is needed to make call to special function that assigns appropriate user data to handling thread. Not a best solution, but that's how it sometimes is with legacy code. What you gonna do?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you're calling the method and in what manner?

Jquery for instance with its [Post](http://docs.jquery.com/Post) method should push all cookies (including your FormsAuth / Session cookie) up with the request that should still authenticate as appropriate.  Bare metal techniques might be making lightweight calls that simply do not push the cookie up...One way to monitor this is by using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to observe the request and a browser based development plugin like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and see what is occuring and amend your JS code as appropriate.

Personally, if you are starting a brand new project and there is no pressing need to expose your services beyond your web application then I would suggest looking at ASP.NET MVC where you can make Jquery / client-side up to the controller and get your authentication wrapped up for free.  I've recently created something simliar using WCF JSON endpoints and some inevitable pain, I then saw MVC and kinda kicked myself...

Comment: I've managed to get some more info on the problem so I edited my question to include those details. It seems that the problem is not in cookies but in legacy code.